# Azure Databricks error- The output of the notebook is too large. Cause: rpc response

Tags: scala, databricks, azure-databricks

Error Message - `job failed with error message The output of the notebook is too large. Cause: rpc response (of 20972488 bytes) exceeds limit of 20971520 bytes`

Details:
We are using databricks notebooks to run the job. Job is running on job cluster. This is a streaming job.
Job started failing with above mentioned error.

We do not have any display(), show(), print(), explain method in the job.

We are not using awaitAnyTermination method in the job as well.

We also tried adding "spark.databricks.driver.disableScalaOutput true" to the job but it still did not work. Job is failing with same error.

We have followed all the steps mentioned in this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/jobs/job-cluster-limit-nb-output

Do we have any option to resolve this issue or to find out exactly which commands output is causing it to go above 20MB limit.

Comment: Do you have `awaitAnyTermination` enabled ?

Comment: Why don't you run it as a jar job ?
[https://docs.databricks.com/jobs.html#jar-jobs-1](https://docs.databricks.com/jobs.html#jar-jobs-1)

Comment: @gatear - we do not have awaitAnyTermination enabled. We have lots of notebook jobs running successfully so if possible we do not want to move to jar job

Answer (score 0):

See the docs regarding [structured streaming in prod](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/production.html#configure-jobs-to-restart-streaming-queries-on-failure).
I would recommend migrating to workflows based on jar jobs because:

```
Notebook workflows are not supported with long-running jobs. Therefore we don’t recommend using notebook workflows in your streaming jobs.
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying using:

```py
%%capture
%run <path_to_your_notebook>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).